# How to calculate proportional width of an image based on its height?

Tags: c#, .net

How to calculate **proportional width** of an image *based on its height*?

I mean we know only an image height only.

```
string pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Settings.ContentFolderPath, file);

Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
src.EndInit();
image.Source = src;
image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image.Height = canvas1.Height;  
image.Width = ???;
```

Thank you!

---

**UPDATES (1)**

Thanks to all folk who have helped me.

And please stupid people don't vote down...

**UPDATES (2)**

The solution:

```
string pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Settings.ContentFolderPath, file);

Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
src.EndInit();
double ratio = src.Width / src.Height; 
image.Source = src;
image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image.Height = canvas1.Height;  
image.Width = canvas1.Height * ratio;
```

Comment: The same way you calculate the proportional *anything*...multiply the width by the common ratio.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes. Can you write out your answer incl. code sample, please...

Comment: Are you saying you want to resize an image of known width and height?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Not at all. We know HEIGHT only.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko then how can you possibly calculate width? Do you have any other inputs? Aspect ratio? Total pixel count?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Well I just read PNG file and assign it like a source for WPF Image.

Comment: Er.. then what's wrong with `Image.Width`?

Comment: This question was voted down because it was incredibly unclear. Try putting more effort into your questions.

Comment: I completely disagree, the point is to find out image width when all you know is the height, sounds like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With known height and width:

```
var ratio = image.Height / image.Width;
```

With known height and ratio:

```
var width = image.Height / ratio;
```

With known width and ratio:

```
var height = image.Width * ratio;
```

You need to know two out of the three to calculate the other.

Comment: I have height , width for image
like 
var width = 900
var height = 800
I am trying to reduce image keeping image aspect ratio

Comment: Hi @HiteshRanaut, then the width of your image should always be 1.125 x the height (9/8ths of the height). or conversely the height should always be 8/9ths of the width. If you need more advice (and probably more timely responses too!), then you'd be better off asking a new question as opposed to a comment. Best, Rich

Comment: Hi @Rich already solved this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

1. calculate the ratio of the width to height:  original width / original height
2. multiply the width/height ratio by the new desired height to get the new width corresponding to the new height.

You can't maintain the original image aspect ratio without knowing the image's original width and height, or the original images width/height ratio (also called aspect ratio).